# Should I use the same firebase project for 2 different but similar android apps

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I have 2 different but similar apps one is for mathematics the other is for biology so I want to integrate Firebase for viewing analytics in this case should I use separate Firebase projects all I should include all my apps in one and the reporting will be separate for both apps or how does it really work.

Comment: The guidance from Firebase is usually: if the apps have separate logos, they should be in separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule for that. If the users of your apps share the same database and and authentication, then you should add both apps in a single Firebase project, otherwise, you should create two different Firebase projects.